# Being unbounded in a limit ordinal implies order type is also a limit?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Whilst trying to follow a proof from my lecture notes, I stumbled upon the following:
$$\gamma \text{ limit, }A\subseteq \gamma, \sup A=\gamma\implies \text{type}(A)\text{ limit}$$ It sounds true, being unbounded in a limit should have a limit for its order type, but I can really put my finger on why exactly that's the case.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and insights!

Comment: A successor ordinal has a biggest element.  If $\operatorname{type}(A)$ were a successor, then $A$ would have a biggest element.  Since $\sup A=\gamma$ that would mean $\gamma\in A\subseteq\gamma$ so $\gamma\in\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks! If you write it as an answer I'll gladly accept it!